# Collection of subClass in BaseClass

Tags: vba

I want to create the following structure:
[image]

I have created the following code:

**Userform with a commandbutton (used to activate the code)**

```
Option Explicit

Public myCollection As Collection

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim subItem As SubClass
    Dim baseItem As BaseClass

    Set baseItem = New BaseClass
    Set subItem = New SubClass

    subItem.itemName = "Something"

    baseItem.addSubItem (subItem)    <---- ERROR ON THIS ROW!

    myCollection.Add (baseItem)
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Set myCollection = New Collection
End Sub
```

**BaseClass**

```
Option Explicit

Private subClassCollection As Collection

Public Sub addSubItem(subItem As SubClass)
    Call subClassCollection.Add(subItem, Key:=subItem.itemName)
End Sub

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Set subClassCollection = New Collection
End Sub
```

**SubClass**

```
Option Explicit

Private sItemName As String

Property Get itemName() As String
    itemName = sItemName
End Property

Property Let itemName(name As String)
    sItemName = name
End Property
```

When I run this code I get the following error "Object doesn't support this property or method" on the highlighted row in the Userform.

I thought this example would be simple enough.. what am I missing?

Comment: `baseItem.addSubItem (subItem)` should be `baseItem.addSubItem subItem`  (There is no way for `subItem` to be converted to something that could be used in an expression such as `(subItem)`.)

Comment: So when I write baseItem.addSubItem (subItem) I actually try to convert something? I am new to VBA/VB syntax.

Comment: The same goes for the expression `(baseItem)`, so just use the object when adding to the collection, i.e. `myCollection.Add baseItem`.  And you need to set `myCollection` to be a `New Collection` at some point.

Comment: Yes, the syntax for calling subroutines is `subname parm1, parm2`.  So you were make the first parameter `(subItem)`, i.e. an expression involving `subItem`.

Comment: Sorry - I had missed your `Set myCollection = New Collection` in your form initialisation.  (I had tested by just running the `CommandButton1_Click` within a normal module, and overlooked that the form would run the `UserForm_Initialize()` code before that.)  So there's no problems with that part of the code - just with the two bracketed parameters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not put brackets around parameters when calling subroutines / methods.  The brackets are forcing VBA to try and evaluate the expression `(subItem)` (for instance), which it can't do.

The following main code should run.  (No guarantees that it is doing the correct thing, but it won't crash at least.)

```
Option Explicit

Public myCollection As Collection

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim subItem As SubClass
    Dim baseItem As BaseClass

    Set baseItem = New BaseClass
    Set subItem = New SubClass

    subItem.itemName = "Something"

    baseItem.addSubItem subItem

    myCollection.Add baseItem
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Set myCollection = New Collection
End Sub
```

---

The syntax for invoking procedures, etc, is something like:

```
procedure parm1, parm2, parm3
```

or (the obsolete version)

```
Call procedure(parm1, parm2, parm3)
```

or (to use a Function)

```
returnValue = procedure(parm1, parm2, parm3)
```