# VBA subclass reference

Tags: excel, vba, class, subclass

[In this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47364055/collection-of-subclass-in-baseclass/51787645#51787645) there is the description of "subclass" usage in VBA. I'm looking for the next step of it: when I have first subitem added I want to use it and don't know how.

When I write `baseItem(1).itemName` it doesn't work.

I assume it's just because that baseItem is not a collection or an array, but I don't know any other way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I assume it's just because that baseItem is not a collection or an
>   array...

The `baseItem` itself is not a collection nor an array. It is just an object of type `BaseClass`. But this object `baseItem` wrapps a collection so we maybe could say it is *almost* a collection.

The problem with this object though is,  that as it is defined now in [the answer you mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47364055/collection-of-subclass-in-baseclass/51787645#51787645), it provides no way how the clients can get to this collection. The class `BaseClass` needs to be modified so it provides *access* to this *inner* collection for the client of this class. With *access* e.g. some `public` function is meant which will return something from this collection.

Add something like this to the `BaseClass`:

```
Public Function getSubItem(index As Variant) As SubClass
    Set getSubItem = subClassCollection.Item(index)
End Function
```

Now objects which will be at runtime created based on this class definition will provide access to the *inner* collection via this function `getSubItem`. The code which will use this function will look like this. So it is now *almost* that what you are trying to achieve.

```
Dim name As String
name = baseItem.getSubItem(1).itemName
Debug.Print name ' Prints "Something" in output window
```

But it could be made even exactly to what you are trying to achieve. When exporting the file of `BaseClass.cls` and adding `Attribute Value.VB_UserMemId = 0` to the very beginning of function `getSubItem` and importing it again to project.

```
Public Function getSubItem(index As Variant) As SubClass
    Attribute Value.VB_UserMemId = 0
    Set getSubItem = subClassCollection.Item(index)
End Function
```

Now you can really write your code exactly that way you wanted. HTH

```
Dim name As String
name = baseItem(1).itemName
Debug.Print name ' Prints "Something" in output window
```

For more information about `Creating A Default Member In VBA` have a look e.g. [here](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/DefaultMember.aspx).

Comment: Great! It works, I don't know why yet, but I keep reading and looking for enlightenment ;)

Answer (score 3):

Welcome to SO!

In vba like many other languages it is a Property.  You call them directly and not numerically, but you need to write GET/LET methods unless the class is public (that is not really encapsulation to simply access directly).

baseItem.itemName would be your call.

But ... As I said before, better that you write accessor(s) to your class as methods.

Here is a guy that sets the tone for OOP in VBA (for me):
https://stackoverflow.com/a/45570268/8716187

He is a driver of the Rubberduck project.

I would ask you to ask yourself if you really need a class, I will often use 4-10 dictionaries of keys holding arrays.  I could wrap them in a class but why bother?  What I need is a searchable and editable ("array"-the dictionary of arrays).

I have very few class modules written, it seems that one can operate without it many times.

-WWC

Comment: Search his answers (Mathieu Guidon) and look for Vitaya as well, there are others, probably too many to name here, but they actively steer you in how to translate parts of VBA into more of a "C language" or OOP structure.

Comment: "Here is a guy that sets the tone for OOP in VBA" - *~blush~*