# VBA - "subobject" of a class

Tags: vba, excel, class

I want to build the structure of skills and those skills areas. For example: skill *multiplication* in the *maths* area.

My areas have some properties (name or weight), and my skills also have properties (name, weight, rank and so on).

I would like to use the following syntax:

```
Areas(1).Skills(2).Name = "solving equations"
```

Is it possible? Thanks [to your help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51788309/vba-subclass-refference) I can now use `Areas(1).Name` in my code and now I'm looking for help with the next step.

I suppose if I have `Areas(1).Skill.Name` syntax, I can handle with adding that index for skills, so the problem is exactly **how to create a "subobject" of a class** (using `Area.Skill.Name` still having the Area as an object)?

Comment: I would guess you have an `Area` class.  If so, you need to add a `Skills` collection containing `Skill` objects to this class.

Answer (score 0):

In order to do that you first need to insert to class modules into you VBA project.

In VBE right clikc your VBA project: *Insert > Class module*.

Add two class modules:

1. First you'll call `Skill` - in properties you'll change the name to `Skill`. Double click it and enter this code there:

   ```
   Public Name As String
   Public Weight As Double
   Public Rank As Long
   'any other fields you want
   ```
2. Second class module - again in properties change the name to `Area`.
   From your description I assumed that you want to have collection of skills there. In order to do that, you need to click *Tools* from ribbon, go to *References* and add *Microsoft.Scripting.Runtime*. Then paste the code for this class:

   ```
   Public Name As String
   Public Weight As Double
   Private pSkill As Collection

   Property Get Skills() As Collection
       Set Skill = pSkill
   End Property

   Property Let Skills(arg As Collection)
       Set pSkill = arg
   End Property
   ```

Note that we don't specify type of elements in `pSkill`, so you need to be careful when dealing with it.

After all this is done, you can use it as you want, like in this code:

```
Sub s()
    Dim s1 As Skills, s2 As Skills
    Set s1 = New Skill
    Set s2 = New Skill
    s1.Name = "solving equations"
    s1.Weight = 2.03
    s1.Rank = 1
    s2.Name = "counting to ten"
    s2.Weight = 1.01
    s2.Rank = 2

    Dim a(1) As Area, someSkills As Collection
    Set someSkills = New Collection

    someSkills.Add s1
    someSkills.Add s2

    Set a(0) = New Area
    a(0).Skill = someSkills

    MsgBox a(0).Skills(1).Name

End Sub
```